# Emacs in terminal creates fake events on insert

Tags: emacs, terminal

When running Emacs in a terminal and inserting text (via `Shift-insert`, `Ctrl+v`, etc...), it seems like Emacs is creating fake events for each character that is inserted. It's like I pressed each character.

So if `f` and `o` have keybindings and the text `foo` is inserted. The functions that the keys `f` and `o` are bound to are triggered.

Why is that? And can I avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: Imagine your current buffer contains a Dired directory (C-x d). What should inserting "foo" do in this case?

Comment: It opens the current file and inserts `oo`

Comment: That's because of the terminal. The terminal recieves the "Paste" and translates it to the key sequence. Emacs with a GUI, however, recieves the "Paste" and can inform you that the buffer is read only etc. The terminal does not know whether emacs that runs in it binds keys to self-insert or something else.

Comment: Anything you can do in Emacs to catch the event and do something custom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run Emacs in a terminal, your key strokes do not directly go to Emacs, but to your terminal emulator program (e.g. gnome-terminal or xterm). The Ctrl-Shift-V is a keybinding of your specific terminal emulator (e.g. it doesn't work that way in xterm) and never seen by Emacs. The terminal specification does not include copy/paste functionality (after all, it's from the time of physical serial terminals connected to your computer, therefore the terminal interface also contains settings like baud rates which don't make sense for a window on your computer). Therefore the terminal emulator has to emulate the effect by sending the individual characters as if you had pressed them. Emacs therefore receives those keypresses, as if you had typed them.

So it is not Emacs which creates the fake events, it's the terminal emulator program which sends them to Emacs. Emacs has no idea whether you pressed those keys yourself, pasted them from somewhere, or used another program to send keypress events to your terminal emulator.

The situation is different if you run Emacs in a window, because then it interacts directly with the windowing system instead of an (emulated) terminal. And the windowing system has dedicated events for copy/paste.